# Moen bathroom faucet leaking at base

Tags: bathroom, leak, faucet

I replaced both cartridges on my moen bathroom faucet and it still appears to be a slow leak at the base, I'm not sure what to do next?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Have you tried [Moen tech support](https://www.moen.com/customer-support)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: How about a few pictures of where it's leaking and the model number.

Comment: I'm probably way off here but would clear caulking work? A photo would be helpful :)

Comment: @MLMerlot caulk would only hide the issue by causing the leaking water to be directed down through the mounting holes and under the cabinet, likely causing even _more_ long-term damage. You're way off. ;)